# sqlite: SELECTing with UNION when the other table does not exist

Tags: sqlite

I have two sqlite3 databases which have tables with identical schemas and (possibly) overlapping data. For example a `Temperature` table in both databases. If I want to get all the columns from both tables combined I will first `ATTACH` the other database:

```
sqlite> ATTACH DATABASE 'old.sqlite' AS Old;
```

and then combine them with `UNION` like this:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM Temperature UNION SELECT * FROM Old.Temperature;
```

This works fine.

However sometimes there is just one table. For example for humidity I might have just one `Humidity` and no counterpart in the other database. In this case the query fails:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM Humidity UNION SELECT * FROM Old.Humidity;
SQL error: no such table: Old.Humidity
```

What I would like to get is all columns from the tables that do exist and not to fail just because the other table doesn't exist.

I don't know before hand which tables exist in which databases. I only have the table names from all the databases combined into one list. And the part of the codebase that's reading the data expects to get all the columns in one query.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Humidity` xD

Comment: That will fail in the case when `Old.Humidity` actually exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to create a query dyncamically in SQL.
(SQLite is designed to be used from within an application written in a 'real' programming language.)

You have to check beforehand whether the table exists (use [PRAGMA table_info](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info), or try if a query using that table works).
Then execute a query either with or without UNION.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I was looking for something similar to `INSERT OR IGNORE...` but looks like that kind of a query does not exist for `SELECT`

Comment: You could execute `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Old.Humidity(...`, but I guess you don't want to modify the old database.